# How to install RxJs

Tags: npm, installation, rxjs

I try to find à SIMPLE way to install rxjs, the reactive programming librairy for JS.
Using npm doesn't seem to work.

All ideas are wellcome
Thank you very mucch

Comment: In what way does npm not seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

1. First you need to install node.JS
2. then install npm install rxjs.

if this is not working then you might have an issue with your variable paths.